# Android - Listview stays empty

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I am currently having a problem implementing a listview in a fragment. 
I used a Hashmap then converted into an arrayList as follows:

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);
    ListView listview = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> portfoliodata = new HashMap<>();
    portfoliodata.put("Test", 23);
    fillMaps.add(portfoliodata);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fillMaps, R.layout.my_adapter_item, new String[] { "AAA","BBB" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    return myView;
}
```

Yet, the result is always a totally blank fragment. Any idea why it is doing so and how I could solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post the contents of R.layout.my_adapter_item.xml

Comment: Do you have android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 in your  listview row  layout

Answer (score 1):

**getActivity()** doesn't exist inside method onCreateView(), because you don't have the Activity's context yet.

You can probe to move your code to onResume() method.

***And remember that you have to connect each column with your data**, something like that:

```
ListView listview;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);

    listview = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    return myView;
} 

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // create the grid item mapping
    String[] from = new String[] {"AAA","BBB"};
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> portfoliodata = new HashMap<>();
    portfoliodata.put("AAA", "Text SampleA");
    portfoliodata.put("BBB", "Text SampleB");
    fillMaps.add(portfoliodata);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), fillMaps, 
        R.layout.my_adapter_item, from, to);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Good luck!